# Finding first letter in a varchar2 Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to automate the data input of a adress data base however some of the housenumber have a letter added to the end of them. Because my database keeps the letter and the number separate i need to somehow split these 2 up. I know that i need a substring for this. My question is however how do i get the location of the first letter.
for example 17b
would give me 3 
where 259a 
would give me 4

Comment: Do you have letters only at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace` for both numbers or letters

```
select regexp_replace('259a', '[A-Za-z]') from dual;
select regexp_replace('259a', '[0-9]') from dual;
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39677)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [`REGEXP_INSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions114.htm#i1239887) or [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) as the standard `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` functions won't have the kind of flexibility that you need.

In your case, you would use something like `REGEXP_INSTR(column_name, '[^0-9 ]')`.